# Quality assessment scale for pre clinical study

Tags: meta-analysis, observational-study

I'm planning a systematic review investigating the mean value of a parameter in the population. The ideal study in my review would be a study where given a variable sample size the investigator analyze mean and standard deviation of this parameter and report this outcome.

I've searched in the web, the most complete reference i found about this is: [this systematic review](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/jebm.12141/abstract). Though i seem i can't find an appropriate scale for assessing quality of the studies. My studies are not randomized, pre clinical.

Any suggestions? Did i miss something? Also does it make sense to assess quality to this studies (i think yes)?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found what i were looking for, but other suggestions are accepted!

Here the reference [Clear Guidelines](http://clear.dol.gov/sites/default/files/CLEAROperationalDescriptiveStudyGuidelines.pdf)